# Glide: error image is not showing while using thumbnail

Tags: android, kotlin, android-glide

I'm using the 3.7.0 version of Glide.

I’m using a thumbnail to show the gif as a loading image and error method to show an error image in the case of the network issue. But, imageview is not showing the error image. It is only showing the thumbnail.

I want to replace the thumbnail with an error image in case of any error.

Here is my code:

```
 fun ImageView.setImageUrlWithThumbnail(
        url: String?,
        @DrawableRes thumbnail: Int = R.drawable.image_loading,
        @DrawableRes error: Int = R.drawable.image_download_failed
) {
    url.let {
        Glide.with(this.context)
                .load(url)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT)
                .thumbnail(Glide.with(this.context).load(thumbnail).error(error))
                .error(error)
                .into(this)
    }
}
```

Comment: If you remove `.thumbnail()`, will it show an error image?

Comment: @CoolMind yes, it will show the error image.

Comment: Because you have a static `thumbnail` (DrawableRes), it is always loaded into memory, and `error` won't be shown.

Comment: Do you know any better solution?

Comment: I think, you should try a listener to load url. I will search.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228830/discussion-between-coolmind-and-parag-rane).